# Add linebreaks after N special characters are observed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a requirement wherein I have a CSV file which has data in a wrong format. However based on the number pipes I need to add a newline character and make the data ready for Consumption.

Can we count the number pipes and add newline `\n`character?

Example:

```
sadasd|asdasd|l||||0sds|sdsds|2||||0sdsd|asdasd|l||||0
```

Expected output:

```
sadasd|asdasd|l||||0   
sds|sdsds|2||||0    
sdsd|asdasd|l||||0    .
```

Comment: At first I was thinking this might be solved by regex, but now I am not sure. I dont quite understand what criterion you want to use to insert a newline

Comment: OH.. do yoyu mean add a newline after the "0" that follows 6 pipes? Why not make the "0" the criterion? or "|0"?

Comment: Why not `mystr.replace("||||||0", "||||||0\n")` ?

Comment: Consumption with a capital C sounds very Ominous

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
_in = "sadasd|asdasd|l||||0sds|sdsds|2||||0sdsd|asdasd|l||||0"

_out = ""
pipeCount = 0
for char in _in:
    if pipeCount == 6:
        _out = _out+char+"\n"
        pipeCount = 0
    else:
        _out = _out+char
    if char == "|":
        pipeCount += 1

print(_out)
```

I am not sure I understood the criterion for adding newline (See comments on question), but my output conforms with your expectation:

```
sadasd|asdasd|l||||0
sds|sdsds|2||||0
sdsd|asdasd|l||||0
```

Output is still a string, but you can just as easily make it a list of string.

Comment: If I have to do it for a file, I just need to read that to variable and apply the same.Am I correct

Comment: Yes...look into `with open` or `csv`Library.
Reading a csv file with `csv` usually is a good place to start: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html